# IProblems with Scan, Strings and TextArea

Tags: java, search, textarea, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to build in a search button. Upon clicking the search button, it will read in the text from JComponent outTextArea.

It will read it each word, and compare each read-in word to the word I'm searching for. My problem is, it works, sorta. It only reads the last word from the outTextArea.

This is the code snippet

```
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Search"))
    {
        String strSearchString = searchTextField.getText();
        System.out.println(strSearchString);

        String text = outTextArea.getText();
        System.out.println(text);

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(text);


        while(sc.hasNext() == true)
        {
            String s = sc.next();

            if (s.equals(strSearchString) == true)
            {
                searchOutLabel.setText("Yes");
            }

            else
            {
                searchOutLabel.setText("Non!");
            }

        }
        sc.close();


    }
```

If I add break; after else, it'll search the first word. So it tells me my logic must be flawed somewhat and it can't be done this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that it will set the text for the label for all words, but will do so so quickly that you won't have time to read it. If you want to do it slowly you'll need to use something to slow down the loop such as a Swing Timer. Also no need for

```
if (suchAndSuch == true)
```

Cleaner to simply do

```
if (suchAndSuch)
```

For example:

```
  if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Search")) {
     final String strSearchString = searchTextField.getText();
     System.out.println(strSearchString);
     String text = outTextArea.getText();
     System.out.println(text);
     final Scanner sc = new Scanner(text);
     int timerDelay = 2 * 1000;

     new Timer(timerDelay, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           if (sc.hasNext()) {
              String s = sc.next();
              if (s.equals(strSearchString)) {
                 searchOutLabel.setText("Yes");
              } else {
                 searchOutLabel.setText("Non!");
              }
           } else {
              ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
              sc.close();
           }
        }
     }).start();
  }
```

**Edit 1**

If you want to print yes if any match has been found, then you'll need to alter your logic to set the textfield if any match is found then exit the method. If no match is found (you've reached the end of the while loop), then set the label there:

```
     while (sc.hasNext()) {
        String s = sc.next();
        if (s.equals(strSearchString)) {
           searchOutLabel.setText("Yes");
           sc.close();
           return;
        }
     }
     searchOutLabel.setText("Non!");         
     sc.close();
```

Comment: No, that's not what I had in mind. I want it to check the whole text it scanned in from the TextArea. And I just want to know if the searched Word I entered in another TextField is in the scanned in text. If it is, "Yes", it's not "No".

Comment: Ah, then your logic is off as it will only check each word and will do so quickly. You must exit your loop once a false is encountered, simple as that.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels better to use break than return as return will return from the method and not run code after the initial if statement. Also I'm not found of you having duplicated sc.close(); in your code make use of the try-finally technique and close the scanner in the finally block.

Answer (score 2):

```
String s = sc.next(); //Change to
String s = sc.nextLine();
```

Similarly change

```
sc.hasNext(); to 
sc.hasNextLine();
```

Also add a `break statement` in your `if true` statement. Like this

```
if (s.equals(strSearchString) == true)
{
  searchOutLabel.setText("Yes");
  break;
}

else
{
```

Then I must comment on your formating preferences. Make me happy and write the above like this

```
if (s.equals(strSearchString)) {
  searchOutLabel.setText("Yes");
  break;
} else {
```